# Metaball problem

Tags: modeling

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyFVc1PbQxQ

I am following this metaball modeling video,

In this video the dude extends objects with fixed edge shapes,

For example in 0:29 ~ 0:30,

the cube is extended z axis  with fixed bevel amount.

When I extend my cube metaball, I get this: [image]

How can I extend with fixed bevel amount? (same with capsule metaball as well, e.g 2:29 )

Answer (score 0):

Yo am I trippin I swear this didn't work in edit mode couple minutes ago

So this can be done in edit mode :P